# Firestore write stream exhausted when exceeding 15 writes per second

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We recently started getting write stream exhausted errors:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.10.0): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Write stream exhausted maximum allowed queued writes.
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.10.0): Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.
```

We're sending a few million transactions in batches of 500 transactions to a firestore collection every 15 seconds. If we run it any more often than every 15 seconds we get the error above. If we exceed it too far, it eventually hard crashes. The advice we got from firebase support was to instead write to a bunch of subcollections, but their limits clearly show 500 writes/second even when writing sequentially to a single collection. Our document ids aren't quite sequential but are often close like `client-id:guid` where client id would often be the same for most of the write. Ideas on what we might be doing wrong/how to fix it? We've tried sending smaller more frequent batches and larger less frequent batches. We created a new project and didn't create any indexes to see if they were a problem. We've sent the requests from different clients, none of which are taxed for resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our issue turned out to the be the batch sizes. We started sending batches of 50 instead of 500 and were able to write about 400/s. We still see the backoff errors but we're not losing any data. I haven't had time to test out the parallel individual writes to see if we can gain a little more write speed but I'll update this answer once I do.

Also, we tried to increase our batch write speeds with the 500/50/5 method they recommend and it still hit the resource exhausted errors.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore does not stop you from exceeding the tresholds below, but doing so affects perfomance, thus the "batches of 500" comes from this [hard limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions) and this [soft limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits).

The main issue here is [hotspotting](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range), since the document IDs are *`client-id:guid` where client id would often be the same for most of the write.* I advised to follow best-practices, or your requests will get queued up, and eventually return `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED`.

Comment: We initially suspected hotspotting as well but I ran a sample of a few million where I had swapped the sequential ids for true guids and it made no difference, and if the calls piled up enough, it actually would completely exhaust the stream and crash the server. We were running batch.commit() with 500 docs but we lowered that to batch to 50 and now we're able to process almost 400/second. We still get the resource exhausted errors but it's writing everything and nothing crashes so I guess that's progress.